# How to create customizable Python type

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I would like to create custom Python type hint that would effectively be

`MyType = Dict[str, <some_type>]`

Then I would like to be able to spesify `MyType` like `MyType[<some_type>]`, for example
`MyType[List[str]]` which would mean `Dict[str, List[str]]`.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

I've tried `MyType = Dict[str, Any]` but I don't know how to make `Any` be a variable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [Generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) answer your question?

```
from typing import TypeVar, Dict, List
X = TypeVar('X')
MyType = Dict[str, X]

def test_f(d: MyType[List[str]]) -> bool:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Python 3.9 or newer, you can [use standard collections directly](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/):

```
StrList = list[str]
MyType = dict[str, StrList]
```

If you're using Python 3.7 or 3.8, you can still use the new notation via

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Note: `__future__` import statements must be located at the very top of a module

Comment: While the mention of standard generic aliases is correct and useful, the code you give doesn't really answer the question. OP actually wanted a generic type that could be specified with one type argument. These are just two type aliases.